# Error when trying to Sandbox with codesign command

Tags: macos, sandbox, codesign, code-signing-entitlements

I am trying to Sandbox my OS X app using the `codesign` command (this is a common lisp app and does not use Xcode).  I have created a very basic enitlements plist that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

and I am calling the `codesign` command:

```
codesign -s - -f --entitlements "/path/to/my/app/MyApp.app/Contents/entitlements.plist" "/path/to/my/app/MyApp.app/"
```

But this command returns the following error:

```
/path/to/my/app/MyApp.app/Contents/entitlements.plist: cannot read entitlement data
```

Does this error mean that I have used the wrong command?  If so what is wrong with the command?

Comment: How do you create your plist. Manually with a text editor or with plist editor.app? The ones that the app produces are binary format not straight XML

Comment: Yeah I've tried using the text editor and plist editor.  How would you suggest I create the plist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xcode generated plist is binary format and looks like this for a fairly standard limited sandbox setup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)com.company.appanme</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
    <string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)com.company.appname</string>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.assets.movies.read-only</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.assets.music.read-only</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.assets.pictures.read-only</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.print</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.document-scope</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

All I can suggest is use Xcode to construct the plist and stripping those keys that you dont want manually. In your case...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I'm just wondering if the `!DOCTYPE` element is required for some reason by the signing tool and the encoding attribute should be upper case.

I've also left in a couple of keys which may be needed even if as you say its a basic lisp app in particular the `com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write` key which will give your process file access.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to get it working when I created the binary entitlements list with XCode.  It does seem a little silly that you need to make a dummy XCode project to create this plist but whatever works.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're right it shouldn't make any difference how you create the plist but playing in Apples playground means using their toys usually. :-(

Answer (score 1):

For people that find this from a Google search:

I got an almost-identical error:

`~/Desktop/Instagram.xcent: cannot read entitlement data`

The solution was to not use `~` in the path, but instead `/Users/...`